# Image exported to file (different number of pixels)

Tags: matlab

I resized an image to 100*100 px. When I export it to a file with Matlab, I get a file with 200 lines and 100 columns...I expected to get a file with 100 lines and 100 columns because the dimension of the picture was 100*100...could anyone tell me, why this doesn't happen? . Thank you.

Comment: I would guess there is something wrong with your code. Please provide [a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: The size of the variable, not of your file. What does `size(I)` return?

Comment: `size(I)` returns `ans =

   100   100`

Comment: I'll use `dlmwrite(filename,I);` instead of my old code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to export the pixel values to a text file (very different from writing it as an jpg or png file, for sharing and archival), all you need to do is `dlmwrite(filename,I);`

Comment: I'll use this function. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped you. It can accept delimiter (which can be a comma or space or tab) as a parameter, to let you choose the format.